# Phone Number Conversion Happening in Excel When Importing CSV

Tags: excel, csv

When I try to save save in Excel as CSV I got from Excel:
[image]

this csv with broken phone numbers:

[image]

How can I export data to csv with the correct phone numbers?

Comment: When importing, indicate that the phone column is "TEXT", not "GENERAL" .. excel sees it as numbers and thinks it's a number - it doesn't understand what a phone # is .. ;)

Comment: i save all columns as text with ' before.
and same result

Comment: I said IMPORT, not save/export ;)  what options are you using during IMPORT ? ie when you open it ? The problems not during the save, the problem is during the LOAD.

Comment: As @Ditto is saying. The problem is not in your EXPORT, it's when you open that CSV that you just created in order to look at it, you use Excel, which then screws up all of your phone numbers. Open that EXPORTed CSV you just made in NotePad and you will probably see Telephone numbers in the format you want to see them in.